# Swift: Display images linked to a timer and slider

Tags: image, swift, timer, slider, label

I'm new to programming and very new to Swift so am in need of help please.

I want to create a view where images will appear and then disappear from the screen at a specific time. The time will be indicated by a label and also a slider. For example, When 5 seconds is indicated on the the label the image will appear, After 10 seconds on the label, the image will disappear. After 15 seconds another image will appear and so on. This would continue for 60 seconds. This time label would also be connected to the slider. I would like to do this completely in code if possible

Any suggestions as to an efficient way to achieve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify for slider part?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The role of the slider is as a visual representation of the time passing. The time displayed on the label will count up to 60 seconds while the images are appearing on the screen. The slider will also be on the screen moving from 0 seconds to 60 seconds. I hope my explanation is easy to understand.

Comment: i'm understand my friend. I try to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, `UISlider` and `NSTimer` to achieve this. Make sure you keep the `NSTimer` instance as a member variable in your `ViewController`

For example, your `viewDidAppear` would start the `NSTimer` with the default interval (lets say 5 seconds):

Your `ViewController` would look something like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    // Connect these outlets via InterfaceBuilder
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider : UISlider!

    var timer : NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        slider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("sliderValueChanged"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.startTimerWithInterval(5)
    }

    func sliderValueChanged()
    {
        let newValue = slider.value
        self.startTimerWithInterval(NSTimeInterval(newValue))
    }

    func timerDidFire()
    {
        // Do something with the imageView
    }

    private func startTimerWithInterval(seconds: NSTimeInterval)
    {
        if self.timer != nil { self.timer.invalidate() }

        self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: seconds, target: self, selector: Selector("timerDidFire"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Erik,

Thank you for taking the time to write this code for me. It is very helpful.

However, When I enter it into Xcode I get 2 errors. 

The first error was not the line:

override func viewDidApppear (animated: Bool)

The error reads:
“method does not override any method from its superclass”


The second error is on the line:
self.startTimerWithInterval(newValue)

This error reads:
“float is not convertible to NSTimeinterval”

Any additional help on this issues would be great. Thanks again for your help

Comment: The first error is likely because your class does not inherit from `UIViewController`. Make sure you have `import UIKit` at the top so Swift can find the Apple framework. The second error is my mistake, I often forget how strongly typed Swift is compared to Objective-C. The solution is to create a `NSTimeInterval` instance using the  `newValue` variable. I have updated my solution to reflect this change.

Comment: Error two is now working. Thanks for that. Unfortunately, error one is still there. I had import UIKit in already as above but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.